# How can I tell a database to only return data in discrete portions?

Tags: database, select, paging

I couldn't find a proper discussion thread on this topic, so I'm going to go ahead and ask here.

Problem: I have a select query that returns a result of size 100,000+. The user wants to view all this data, but obviously I can't give it to him all at once. I also don't want to store so much data on the client's memory. I want the user to be able to "page through" the results, being able to view the data in pages of 500 records.

So, how can I ask the database to only send me back 500 records at a time?

Comment: Which database platform?

Comment: what type of Database, are you talking about sql server

Comment: Right now I am using Sybase, but we may be switching to Oracle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This depends on the database you are using, but in MySql you could try something like:

```
SELECT * FROM MyTable LIMIT <start>, 500
```

and replace `<start>` with the index you would like to start on (e.g. 0 for the first page, 501 for the second page).

Answer (score 1):

You can use a combination of [rownumber](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx) and [top](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189463.aspx) (atleast in SQL server)